# Problems to install windows 10 and Linux uing UEFI

Tags: linux, windows, boot, uefi, grub2

I want to install windows 10 and linux (ubuntu 21 or debian 11) in a new SSD (480 GB). But I have some problems with that, first I installed Windows 10, it created some partitions:
sda1 (100 MB -> EFI System), sda2 (16 MB -> Microsoft reserved), sda3 (194,7 GB -> Microsoft basic data) and sda4 (518 MB -> Windows recovery environment). And then I installed ubuntu 21, in the installation didn't recognize the windows installation.

When I start this goes to windows SO, when I select in BIOS the ubuntu, this has an error about /boot/vmlinuz.

Now I started by a live ubuntu, and this is the information with fdisk:

kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2,03 GiB, 2181812224 bytes, 4261352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 447,13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C3887667-AC2B-42B3-9E9E-39558477EDA8

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 408535333 408295718 194,7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  408537088 409597951   1060864   518M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  409597952 761942015 352344064   168G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  761942016 927956991 166014976  79,2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  927956992 937701375   9744384   4,6G Linux swap
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
```

When I want to recovery grub doing:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```

The answer is:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform. grub2-install: warning: this GPT
partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be
possible. grub2-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can
only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However,
blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub2-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

I tried in several ways from BIOS configuration (Asus Maximus VII Hero). There were some problems to recognize the installation USB, so I had to use DVD.

Comment: You did not boot Linux in UEFI mode. This is however required here. Make sure to boot in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't need GRUB to recognize Windows – you can choose "Windows Boot Manager" straight from your firmware boot menu. The two bootloaders can coexist in UEFI. (Booting Windows without going through GRUB can also have advantages for BitLocker.)

> `Installing for i386-pc platform. grub2-install: warning: this GPT`

This says you're trying to install the BIOS version of grub2, not the UEFI version. Try specifying UEFI explicitly, as well as manually specifying the filesystem paths:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi --boot-directory=/mnt/boot
```

(For UEFI, the bootloader is installed to a mounted filesystem, not to a disk, so you do not need to specify "/dev/sda2".)

It is possible that your live Kubuntu system has the wrong 'grub2' package installed. In Debian and Ubuntu, the different GRUB "target system" files (`i386-pc` for BIOS, `x86_64-efi` for UEFI) are split out into separate packages, instead of all files being available at once. If needed, try:

```
apt install grub-efi-amd64{,-bin,-signed}
```

Note: If you've booted the Kubuntu live system in BIOS mode, it won't be able to create the UEFI NVRAM entry pointing at the newly installed grub2. Check whether `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` exists; if it doesn't – reboot and carefully select the "UEFI:" option in your motherboard's boot menu.

(If that doesn't help, you can sometimes work around the issue by installing grub2 twice, adding the `--removable` option for the 2nd attempt.)